# Google closure-compiler complaining about undeclared variable in typeof call

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

I am minifying JavaScript for a typical modern browser (eg. Chrome 64) using Google's closure-compiler v20180101. The same code compiled without errors for v20170409. I am using the same piece of JS in multiple a several different packaging contexts and would rather not split things into many tiny files.

Instead, I've added some conditional code that uses `typeof` to see if some functions are already defined and if not, define them.

This is a very basic example:

```
if (typeof foo === 'undefined') {
  foo = function() { return "Foo!"; }
}
```

In response to this, clojure-compiler-v20180101 complains of:

```
foo.js: ERROR - variable foo is undeclared
```

I can add an extern file that declares `var foo`, but this seems to defeat the purpose of the `typeof` check. Also, in other situation `foo` gets declared twice which closure-compiler also complains about.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Is this for a global variable?  If not, why are you trying to use an undeclared variable? Maybe that's what you meant by packaging contexts?

Comment: @SkinnyPete - It's an external function, but not in every context. I am trying to create conditional logic based on whether the function is defined or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare the variable:

```
/** @suppress {duplicate} */
var foo;
if (typeof foo === 'undefined') {
  foo = function() { return "Foo!"; }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, adding a declaration causes a 'declared twice' error. I am trying create conditional logic based on if `foo()` is defined or not. This works in standard JavaScript, but closure-compiler errors and I do not want to disable this error class entirely.

Comment: @saarp I edited the answer to show how to suppress the error for a single statement.